# Parent wrapping child class method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, abstract-class

I have these Worker classes doing some job:

```
class WorkerOne implements IWorker {
    @Override
    public doWork(Resource resource){
     // do some work
    }
}
```

**I want all `doWork()` methods to be wrapped by the same operation.**

One way to achieve it is creating an abstract class as the following example:

```
abstract class WorkWrapper implements IWorker {
    @Override
    public doBetterWork(){
       Resource resource = // ...
       doWork(resource)
       resource .close();
    }
}


class WorkerOne extends WorkWrapper {

    protected doWork(Resource resource){
     // do some work
    }
}
```

and invoke the Worker as:

```
WorkerOne worker = new WorkerOne();
worker.doBetterWork();
```

For some reasons I prefer not to use inheritance. Is there a better solution to do this wrapping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `default` method that you can defined in interfaces you could avoid inheritance (`extends`) and stick to implement (`implements`) :

```
class WorkerOne implements IWorker {
    @Override
    public void doWork(Resource resource){
     // do some work
    }
}

public interface IWorker {
    void doWork(Resource resource);

    default void doBetterWork(){
       Resource resource = // ...
       doWork(resource)
       reource.close();
    }
}
```

And use it like you previously did :

```
IWorker worker = new WorkerOne();
worker.doBetterWork();
```

> I want all doWork() methods to be wrapped by the same operation.

Personally I don't like very much designs where I expose two methods in terms of API while only one of them should be invoked by clients of the class. That is misleading.
To avoid it, I would probably use composition and decorator (not the conventional decorator as the signature differs between the two `doWork()` methods).

```
public interface IWorker {
    void doWork(Resource resource);
}

class WorkWrapper{

    private IWorker decorated;
    public WorkWrapper(IWorker decorated){
       this.decorated = decorated;
    }
    @Override
    public doWork(){
       Resource resource = // ...
       decorated.doWork(resource);
       reource.close();
    }
}

class FooWork implements IWorker {

    @Override
    public doWork(Resource resource){
          // do something...
    } 
 }
```

Now no ambiguities is possible :

```
WorkWrapper worker = new WorkWrapper(new FooWork());
worker.doWork(); // just this method is exposed now in WorkWrapper
```

You can combine it to the factory to make things simpler and hiding implementation details from client side:

```
WorkWrapper worker = FooWork.createWrapperFor();
worker.doWork();
```

Answer (score 2):

The situation you are describing seems to be the exact context where one would apply the [Template Method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/template-method-design-pattern/) design pattern. However, that patterns does, indeed, call for inheritance.

There are alternatives. However, it's such a good fit for your requirements that I would hesitate to call them "better" solutions.

The obvious alternative to inheritance is composition. In your case this would mean applying the [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern.

In applying this pattern your `WorkWrapper` would become the *context*, and the `IWorker` would match the role of the *abstract strategy*, with its implementations serving as the *concrete strategies*.

In code:

```
class WorkWrapperContext {
    private IWorker strategy;

    WorkWrapperContext(IWorker strategy) { 
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public void doBetterWorkOperation() {
        // do some stuff
        strategy.doWork();
    }
}
```